# Cordova: judge whether the page is opened in a device app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, web, user-agent

I'm using cordova, and serving the site (remote, not local file in the cordova app project) to either ordinary browser and the specific app install on my phone.

Now comes the question, if the page is opened inside the app, the cordova script should be introduced, while if it is opened under an ordinary browser, that shouldn't happen.

So I wonder if there is a way to tell whether the page is open inside the app?

```
if (isApp()) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
        bootstrap();
    }
} else {
    bootstrap();
}
```

I spy the `UserAgent` in both case, it seemed there isn't any significant information there.

Or if I can add some `UserAgent` information in the cordova project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to `/config.xml`.

See: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/index.html#Android%20Configuration

```
<preference name="AppendUserAgent" value="Cordova" />
```

Then, we can use the follwing condition in the very early time to judge:

```
function isApp() {
    return /Cordova/.test(windows.navigator.userAgent);
}
```

We can event decide whether to introduce the cordova.js:

```
let cordovaReady = null;

if (/Cordova/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
  cordovaReady = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/cordova/cordova.js';
    script.onload = () => {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
        resolve();
      }, false);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });
} else {
    cordovaReady = Promise.reject();
}

// We got cordovaReady as a Promise that tells both `inApp()` and `deviceready`.
cordovaReady.then(() => { // done
    // windows.cordova is available
}, () => { // fail
    // windows.cordova is undefined
    console.log('The page is not open under Cordova App.');
}).then(() => { // always
    // launch your app
    bootstrap();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test for `window.cordova` to determine if your app is running in a Cordova environment (ie. *cordova.js* is included in the page)

Comment: I want to know before that, to dicide whether to introduce the `cordova.js`